# Ajax GET request always fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to connect to a server and get a Json that contains an id that I need. 
The request fails every time. I'm new to javascript and can't figure out what the problem can be.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://www.dais.unive.it/~cosmo/esercitazione3/captcha.php?getIdentifier',
                timeout: 2000
            }).done(function(data){
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                var session_id = obj.id;
                $("#test").append("Session id: "+ session_id + "<br/>");

            }).fail(function(){
                alert("Error");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you define "fails"? What is the HTTP status code you are getting? Is it 200?

Comment: It's a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.dais.unive.it/~cosmo/esercitazione3/captcha.php?getIdentifier. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43429678/7751463

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code , just add jsonp datatype

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

           $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.dais.unive.it/~cosmo/esercitazione3/captcha.php?getIdentifier',
 dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (response) {
       console.log(response.id);
var session_id=response.id;
 
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
      console.log("FAILURE");
   
    },
});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I guess I should be connected to my university network to get it work with my code.

Comment: dear sguci please click up arrow and give the tick mark if answer works .

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you are not authorized to get data from this server due to the **same-origin policy** implemented in all web browsers.

Here you have two solutions:

1. JSONP (JSON with padding)
2. CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

Since you try to access a URL from the website of your university, I guess you are not the system administrator. Thus, you cannot use CORS which is based on HTTP headers that require some configuration on the server-side.

However, you should be able to use JSONP. With jQuery, this is very easy: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand the kind of issue that occurred